# Getting 403 Forbidden when using proxy

Tags: c#, proxy, httpclient

I try to use a rotating proxy with my application.

The following code works:

```
var cookies = new CookieContainer();
var proxy = new WebProxy("host")
{
    Credentials = new NetworkCredential("userName", "password")
};
var clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler { CookieContainer = cookies };
clientHandler.Proxy = proxy;

var client = new HttpClient(clientHandler);
Console.WriteLine(await client.GetStringAsync("http://lumtest.com/myip.json"));
```

However, when I try to actual use it with my application, I'm getting `The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.`

If I remove the line of setting proxy to handler (`clientHandler.Proxy = proxy`), it works.
Not sure if it something with the specific website or something I missed with the proxy.

*The requests which doesn't work are both GET and POST and User-Agent is define as header (in addition to other headers)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apparently, after contact proxy support, it was issue from their side.

edit as I was asked:
The help desk of the proxy service I used, told me to configure options like targeting HTTPS domains, without this configuration on my profile, I got a 403 error

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).